# Extending types of a library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'd like to extend the bytebuffer library (https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js) by two functions, but I am struggling with the types (it always says "[ts] Property 'myNewMethod' does not exist on type 'ByteBuffer'").

**My bytebuffer-sc.ts (which is supposed to extend the bytebuffer lib):**

```
import { prototype } from 'bytebuffer';

// In the next line it says: Property 'myNewMethod' does not exist on type 'ByteBuffer'.
prototype.myNewMethod = (offset: number) => {

}
```

**My src/types/bytebuffer-sc.extend.d.ts:**

What I have tried to add the "myNewMethod" to the types (what unfortunately didn't work):

```
import * as ByteBuffer from 'bytebuffer';

declare module 'bytebuffer' {
  ByteBuffer.prototype.myNewMethod: (offset: number) => number;
}
```

Updated (second try):

```
import * as ByteBuffer from 'bytebuffer';

declare module 'bytebuffer' {
  export interface ByteBuffer {
    calculateVarint32: (value: number) => number;
  }
}
```

**My question:**

How do I properly extend the types of a given "class library" by another method?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea but have implemented it wrong.

The declaration to extend the type must be:

```
declare module 'bytebuffer' {
    export interface ByteBuffer {
        myNewMethod: number => number;
    }
}
```

After you do this, then you can assign the actual method to the prototype:

```
ByteBuffer.prototype.myNewMethod = (offset: number) => { };
```

TypeScript needs you to tell it that a property/method exists before you can assign it. You were mixing the declaration and the actual assignment.

Comment: Actually I was a bit too fast with accepting your answer. Your approach doesn't work. It still says that the method does not exist. Also: If I leave the import in the .d.ts file it doesn't recognize any of the existing type definitions anymore.

Comment: Can you post the new .d.ts file? This approach should work ... I've used it to extend RxJS's `Observable`.

Comment: Done. Basically I am trying to fix the typings for my project because someone created wrong types on the definetelyTyped repo. It should be "calculateVarint32" instead of "calculateVariant32". I can't wait until definetelyTyped accepts my pull request.